# cypher query in py2neo to update n Nodes with a list of n ids and parameters

Tags: neo4j, cypher, py2neo

Say I want to update a sizeable amount of already existing nodes using data that, for instance, is stored in a `pd.Dataframe`. Since I know how to write a parametrized query that will handle a single node update, my basic solution is to set this query in a loop and run it for each row in the data frame.

```
for _,row in df.iterrows():
    query='''MATCH (p:Person)
             WHERE p.name={name} AND p.surname = {surname}
             SET p.description={description} '''


    tx.run(query,name=row['name'],surname=row['surname'],
           description=row['description'])
```

However, there must be a more direct (and faster) way of passing this information to the query, so that the iteration is "managed" at the server side. Is that true? I haven't been able to find any documentation for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of looping like this, with one Cypher query executed per entry, you should gather all that into a list parameter of map objects and make a single Cypher query (you could batch this though if you have > 100k or so entries to process). Michael Hunger has a [good blog entry on this approach](https://medium.com/neo4j/5-tips-tricks-for-fast-batched-updates-of-graph-structures-with-neo4j-and-cypher-73c7f693c8cc).

You can use UNWIND on the list parameter to transform it into rows, and handle everything all at once. Assuming you pass in the list as `data`:

```
UNWIND $data as row
MATCH (p:Person)
WHERE p.name = row.name AND p.surname = row.surname
SET p.description = row.description
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by runnin a cypher [LOAD](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/load-csv/) query and providing a csv file containing your data:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///file.csv' as csvLine fieldterminator ';' 
MATCH (p:Person {name:csvLine.name, p.surname:csvLine.surname})
SET p.description=csvLine.description
```

But I don't think there is a solution to pass array of data to a match loop.

Comment: It feels like a bit of a hack... But thanks anyway. Let's see if something better comes.

Answer (score 1):

The essential problem is already addressed in the answer by InverseFalcon, but to provide a complete answer including the `py2neo` and `pandas bits`, I post the code below:

```
query='''UNWIND {batch} AS row
         MATCH (p:Person)
         WHERE p.name=row.name AND p.surname = row.surname
         SET p.description=row.description '''

graph.run(query,batch=df.to_dict(orient='records'))
```

So, at the end this was more of a `neo4j` than a `py2neo` question, and the relevant piece of info in neo4j's docs is [here](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.4/cypher/clauses/unwind/#unwind-creating-nodes-from-a-list-parameter)

Comment: How do you achieve the same when your df is a pyspark dataframe?